# Como remover o background do QPushButton?

Tags: pyqt-5, widget

Eu estou tentando criar um texto clicável — como "[esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)" — no Qt Designer. Para isso, eu criei um `QPushButton` e marquei a propriedade `flat` para remover o *background* do botão.

Na primeira vista, o background parece ter sido removido, mas quando eu passo o mouse em cima, o mesmo aparece novamente. Como eu posso remover esse background definitivamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu ainda não entendo o porquê da seguinte propriedade alterar o *background* do botão, mas para remover o *background* por completo, defina a propriedade `border` para `none`, da seguinte forma:

```
QPushButton: flat {
    border: none;
}
```